# What is the $\Theta$ of $ (lg n) ^ n$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I think it has to be $nlgn$ because the log of the said function is $nlglgn$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lg n$ grows faster than a constant, $(\lg n)^n$ grows faster than any exponential: much faster than $n \lg n$.

You can write $(\lg n)^n$ as $2^{n \lg \lg n}$ if it helps you have intuition for how big it is, but either form is "simplified": there's no simpler expression with the same $\Theta$.